# mysql to mongodb query conversion issue

Tags: mongodb-query

Iam new to mongodb. I try to convert this mysql query to mongodb, but iam getting only (appId & count). Actually i want (date & count).

**original query**

```
SELECT count(distinct appID),created_date 
FROM table 
where created_date between 2015-1-1 and 2015-1-20 
group by created_date
```

**mongodb query**

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [{ $match : { createdDate: { $gt : ISODate("2015-05-01T00:00:00.000Z"), $lte : ISODate("2015-05-20T23:59:59.000Z")}}},
    {  $group : { _id : { year: { $year: "$createdDate" },month: { $month: "$createdDate" },day: { $dayOfMonth : "$createdDate" },appId : "$appId"}}},
    {  $group : { _id : { appIdd: '$_id.appId'}, count: { $sum: 1 }}},
    { $project: { _id : 0,appId: '$_id.appIdd', count: 1}}
    ])
```

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to get the needed result by the following query:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [{ $match : { createdDate: { $gt : ISODate("2015-05-01T00:00:00.000Z"), $lte : ISODate("2015-05-20T23:59:59.000Z")}}},
    {  $group : { _id : { year: { $year: "$createdDate" },month: { $month: "$createdDate" },day: { $dayOfMonth : "$createdDate" },appId : "$appId"}}},
    {  $group : { _id : { appIdd: '$_id.appId'}, count: { $sum: 1 }}},
    { $project: { created_date_str: { $concat: ["$_id.year","-","$_id.month","-","$_id.day","T00:00:00Z"] }, count: 1}},
    { $project: { _id : 0, created_date: { ISODate("$created_date_str") }, count: 1}}
    ])
```